# How to match multiple domain variations in Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I need to macth below example domains for the Chrome extension.

```
https://network1.com
https://network2.com
```

Rather than hardcoding, is it possible to match the domains with regular expression?

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
     "matches": [
        "*://network*.com/*",
      ]
   }
```

I have tried this but Chrome throws error.

Comment: Please see this. [Match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/match_patterns/)

Comment: No, content scripts don't support regular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/match_patterns/) mentions,

`https://*foo/bar` is a bad (invalid) pattern because `*` in the host can be followed only by a `.` or `/`.

So, you cannot use a substring match pattern like yours.

However, if the dynamic part in URL was a sub-domain like `1.network.com` and `2.network.com`, you could use the pattern `https://*.network.com`.